# How to upgrade rooted HTC Desire with Unrevoked3 (Clockworkmod) to Froyo 2.2?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, updates, htc-desire, clockworkmod-recovery, unrevoked

I recently rooted my HTC Desire having Froyo 2.2 with Unrevoked3. Rooting was successful, however, after Unrevoked placed the recovery image, the system was back at OS 2.1 again.

How can I upgrade again back to Froyo 2.2? Installing the normal OTA update doesn't work I guess.  At least it didn't when I tried. Can someone provide me some hints on how to do so? (Sorry, but it was my first rooting adventure.)

Comment: I'm stuck between posting this question again, or just commenting here: The original question has been asked many times on this forum, and I have yet to see someone actually answer it.

I was sent here by Google, because I want to know how to remove the recovery image that Unrevoked put on my HTC Desire. I want to be able to receive OTA updates again.

Except everytime I find a similar question, someone says to try a different custom rom. Please, if there is anyone out there who knows the answer to the original question, please will you post a reply.

(apologies to FoleyIsGood - this is

Answer (score 4):

If you have succesfully rooted the phone and have the ClockworkMod recovery image, you can easily flash a custom 2.2 ROM.

Have a look on [MoDaCo](http://android.modaco.com/category/430/htc-desire-desire-modaco-com/) for some good options. You should also install the Rom Manager app from the market for easy flashing, booting to recovery, backups, etc.

You shouldn't have to wait long before there are plenty of 2.3 options too :) (there are a couple already on the XDA forums, but these are very new so you might want to wait just a little while whilst all the kinks are ironed out).