# Is it possible to update HTC desire to 2.2 with unrooted?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-desire, updates

I bought a new HTC Desire (will arrive in a few days).
The phone is not branded (or unbranded) will arrive with version 2.1, and I want to update to 2.2.

After a lot of reading I realized I need to create a goldcard. So I bought a 2GB microSD card and I will create the goldcard when the phone arrives.

I also read about rooting the phone, which means (from what I understood) to flash the phone's ROM.

What I want to know is do I have to root the phone in order to update to 2.2 ???

Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-android-2-2-froyo and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3911/upgrade-rooted-htc-desire-with-unrevoked3-clockworkmod-to-froyo-2-2

Comment: Thanks :-)
but none of these related posts answers my question...

Comment: You should get an OTA update to 2.2 without rooting. If you *want* to root to install a custom ROM then you don't need a goldcard - use unrevoked instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTC provide OTA-update to 2.2 for HTC Desire. You don't need any special (root or goldcard) to update your phone. Just connect your phone to Wi-Fi or 3G

Comment: Hey Vitus - thanks for your answer :-).
I read/header about some cases that if you don't update with gold card (even using OTA) some wifi issues appear (http://www.htcdesireforum.com/htc-desire-troubleshooting/wifi-%27error%27-after-installing-android-2-2/)

With that, I must add that I am total newbie in android, so maybe I am missing something out.